# How to Display lines between two text and forward to a file in UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix, for-loop

I need to display data between two text and append it to a file depending upon the first text.

For example, I have below data

```
Enable
S001
1106813,1107231,8012300
S021
2013123,2012321,
1105123,1109231,
1109234

disable
S022
2705115,2708215,

enable
S002
1123112,1140230,2315120
```

In the above text I need to add all the enable data(data starting with enable and till next disable headline) into a file name enable.txt and disable data( data starting with disable text and till next available enable text) into disable.txt

and I want the data to be formatted such that the data after S*** till next S*** should be in a single line separated with comma.

I need to automate the above task. 
I could get the line no of each enable and disable text heading using grep -n but how I should start a loop such that it check for each line no I got and if it is enable then till next line no it should go to enable.txt and same for disable.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: What about the second `enable` - where does that have to go?

Comment: @Jayesh: I have just got line no and after that I am thinking of creating an array of line no and then loop through array and on the basis of text I need to redirect the output to a file

Comment: @MarkSetchell: it is just a sample in this way there are many enable and disable and for each enable and disable values I have to repeat the patteren

Comment: Please, show what you have tried until now. If you're lost and are in search for some clues, try to take a look at `sed` or `awk`...

Comment: enDisArr=$(egrep -ni 'enable|disable' Stu_data.txt|cut -d':' -f1)

Comment: enDisArr=$(egrep -ni 'enable|disable' Stu_data.txt|cut -d':' -f1)

I have tried to create array first with above command which is not working ..

after that I thought of using the below set of commands
no_of_lines=$(egrep -ci 'enable|disable')


for (( count=1; count<=$no_of_lines; count++ ))
do
  start=$(expr enDisArr[$count]+1)
  end=$($enDisArr[expr ($count+1)] -1)
 [ $(sed -n "$count p" Stu_data.txt |tr [:lower:] [:upper:]) = "ENABLE" ] && sed -n "$start , $end p" >> enable.txt || sed -n "$start , $end p" >>disable.txt 
done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have grep the position of enable and disable using egrep -in 'enable|disable' file-name
and stored those into array
then traversed through (each element of array)
  .. if (the value at current count is enable )
       then 
         target_file is enable.txt 
      otherwise 
         target_file is disable.txt

```
 Lines from current position+1 to next position-1 has been moved to the target_file

 when (the last value in the array is reached)
  then 
    the value from current position+1 to no_of_lines in file has been copied to target_file
```

end

and I am able to get the result in enable and disable files...:)

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started...

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}
    /^enable/  {if(length(s))print s > f; s=""; f="enable.txt"; next}
    /^disable/ {if(length(s))print s > f; s=""; f="disable.txt";next}
    {if(length(s))s=s "," $0; else s=$0}' yourfile
```

In the `BEGIN` part, I set IGNORECASE so that upper/lower case is ignored and it will work if I see `Enable` or `enable`.

If there is a line that starts with `enable`, I print `s` (my output string) to the last filename I saved (in variable `f`) and clear my output string.

Likewise if the line starts with `disable`.

On all other lines, I append the current line to my output string `s`, adding in a comma if the string already contains anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can have:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { RS = "" }
$1 ~ /^[Ee]nable$/ { out = "/dev/stdout" }
$1 ~ /^[Dd]isable$/ { out = "/dev/stderr" }
{
    printf "%s", $2 > out
    for (i = 3; i <= NF; ++i) {
        sub(/,$/, "", $i)
        printf $i ~ /^S/ ? "\n%s" : ",%s", $i > out
    }
    print "" > out
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f script.awk input_file.txt >enable.txt 2>disable.txt
```

Output (Enabled):

```
S001,1106813,1107231,8012300
S021,2013123,2012321,1105123,1109231,1109234
S002,1123112,1140230,2315120
```

Output (Disabled):

```
S022,2705115,2708215
```

Comment: Thanks konsolebox
Please help me to understand the below text 
' printf "%s", $2 > out'  
and the problem is gsub does not work in my terminal

Comment: @Jagdeep You mean `gsub` doesn't work in `awk`? But still I already changed it to `sub`. `printf "%s", $2 > out` prints the first line after Enable/Disable to stdout (enabled) or stderr (disabled).

Comment: Thanks for replying ..
i created script.awk with ur commands and try to run, unfortunately no result.. enable and disable files are empty

Comment: @Jagdeep You may check if your text file is not in UNIX format. You can convert it with `dos2unix` or `sed -i 's|\r|| file`.

Comment: the data is in unix format only as I have copied the data and then did vi filename and paste the data ..
anyway I have used ur sed command also

Answer (score 1):

Iin order to parse such file, you might use a simple finite state automaton using your favorite script language. Here I use `awk`:

```
cat testfile |  awk '/^[eE]nable/ { state = 1; }
         /^[dD]isable/ { state = 2 }
         /^S.*/ && (state==1) 
         /^[S0-9].*/ && (state==1) { printf("%s%s",$0, ($0~/,$/) ? "":"\n") > "enable.txt"; }
         /^[S0-9].*/ && (state==2) { printf("%s%s",$0, ($0~/,$/) ? "":"\n") > "disable.txt"; }
    '
```

Given you input file, I have this result:

```
sh$ cat enable.txt
S001
1106813,1107231,8012300
S021
2013123,2012321,1105123,1109231,1109234
S002
1123112,1140230,2315120

sh$ cat disable.txt
S022
2705115,2708215,
```

Please note you sample file is (maybe) ill formated at there is a trailing `,` at the end of the *disable sentance*.

---

**EDIT** A slight variation, just for fun:

```
cat testfile |  awk 'BEGIN { state = "unknown" }
         /^[eE]nable/ { state = "enable"; }
         /^[dD]isable/ { state = "disable" }
         /^S.*/ { print $0 > (state ".txt") }
         /^[0-9].*/ { printf("%s%s",$0, ($0~/,$/) ? "":"\n") > (state ".txt"); }
    '
```

Comment: Thanks for replying ..

I tried ur later pasted script and got the below error , I tried using '$' with state variable still the error is same

awk: syntax error at source line 4
 context is
          /^S.*/ { print $0 > >>>  $state".txt" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 4
awk: syntax error at source line 5

Comment: @Jagdeep This is `awk` not `bash`: variable does _not_ use a `$` to access their content. The only exceptions are `$0`, `$1` ... which are bound to the matching pattern. Moreover, in `awk` [string concatenation](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_60.html) does not require any operator. So `state ".txt"` does means _'concatenate the content of the variable `state` to the literal ".txt" in order to produce a new string'_. I've edited my later answer to add some parenthesis in order to put emphasis on those concatenations (tested with _mawk 1.3.3_)